# Uncaught Error: Component 'my-component': Unknown viewModel value: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created a page on which I want to load a second Oracle Jet component. Whenever I load this page it gives me below error message:

```
 knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3758 Uncaught Error: Component 'my-component': Unknown viewModel value: [object Object]
            at knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3758
            at resolveViewModel (knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3704)
            at Object.loadViewModel (knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3605)
            at Object.getFirstResultFromLoaders [as _getFirstResultFromLoaders] (knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3507)
            at knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:3641
            at Object.execCb (require.js:1696)
            at Module.check (require.js:883)
            at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1139)
            at require.js:134
            at require.js:1189
```

below are the code snippets :

```js
    define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'appController','ojs/ojmodule','ojs/ojbutton'],
     function(oj, ko, $, app) {
      
        function CustomerViewModel() {
          var self = this;
          
       
          self.buttonClick = function(event){
           
                 // return true;
          };
        // Header Config
          self.headerConfig = {'viewName': 'header', 'viewModelFactory': app.getHeaderModel()};

      ko.components.register('my-component', {
        viewModel: { require: 'viewModels/register' },
        template: { require: 'text!views/register.html' }
    });

        }

        
        return new CustomerViewModel();
      }
    );
```

```html
    <div class="oj-hybrid-applayout-page">
      <div class="oj-applayout-fixed-top">
          <!--
           ** Oracle JET V4.2.0 hybrid mobile application header pattern.
           ** Please see the Oracle JET Cookbook App Shell: Hybrid Mobile demos for
           ** more information on how to use this pattern.
        -->
        <header role="banner" class="oj-hybrid-applayout-header" data-bind="ojModule: headerConfig">
        </header>
      </div>
      <!-- This is where your main page content will be loaded -->
      <div class="oj-applayout-content">
        <div role="main" class="oj-hybrid-applayout-content">
          <div class="oj-hybrid-padding">
            <h1>Hello Customer! Welcome to MyApp. Please Login with your credentials or Register yourself</h1>
                <div id='buttons-container'>      
                   <button id= "button"
            data-bind="click: buttonClick,
                       ojComponent: { component: 'ojButton', label: 'Login' }">
                    <button id= "button"
            data-bind="click: buttonClick,
                       ojComponent: { component: 'ojButton', label: 'Register' }">
                

                </div id='load_Component'>
               
                <div data-bind='component: "my-component"'></div>
              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

I am trying to load my-component in the `load_Component`  tag. I gave the reference of my-component which is defined in respective javascript with the component customer. Please see the image for the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

The error is where you declare your viewModel:

```
  ko.components.register('my-component', {
                viewModel: { require: 'viewModels/register' },
                template: { require: 'text!views/register.html' }

viewModel should be instead:

viewModel: require('viewModels/register')
```

or

```
const RegisterViewModel = require('viewModels/register')

viewModel: RegisterViewModel
```

But anyhow, you shouldn't pass an object to the view model

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you please let me know how can i load that component .
I tried your change but stil it is not working.

Comment: Hello, by changing what I suggested in my comment, does it change the error message?

Comment: How have you updated your component? If you are passing an object youwill get it. Please, edit your question with the code from the viewmodel and also where you declare it (where the error happen)